# Loop and render elements not working in React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I couldn't understand why it is not working. It is showing me error cannot find name 'contentItem'. Any suggestions ?

```
const CONTENT = [
{
    title: 'Лицевой счет 256215492543',
    sub_title: 'ул.Неизвестная, 78/9,',
    count: true
},
{
    title: 'Лицевой счет 12356215492543',
    sub_title: 'ул.Неизвестная, 72/7,',
    count: false
},
....
renderContent(section, _, isActive, CONTENT) {
    return (   
      CONTENT.map(contentItem => (
        if (contentItem.special) {
          return(
            <View>
              <Text>{contentItem.title} spec</Text>
          </View>
          )
        }
        return(
          <View style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
            <Text>{contentItem.sub_title} </Text>
          </View>
        )
      });
```

Basic idea, is to show TITLE if "count" is TRUE, if "count" false show SUB_TITLE

Comment: how are you calling the renderContent can you show?

Comment: <Accordion
                        activeSections={activeSections}
                        sections={CONTENT}
                        touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
                        expandMultiple={true}
                        renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
                        renderContent={this.renderContent}
                        onChange={this.setSections}
                    />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change the map function, in the js array map function, it will have three arguments, you can look at the API about [map](https://www.javascripture.com/Array)

```
const CONTENT = [
{
    title: 'Лицевой счет 256215492543',
    sub_title: 'ул.Неизвестная, 78/9,',
    count: true
},
{
    title: 'Лицевой счет 12356215492543',
    sub_title: 'ул.Неизвестная, 72/7,',
    count: false
},
renderContent(section, _, isActive, CONTENT) {
    return (   
      CONTENT.map((item,index)=> {
        if (item.count) {
          return(
            <View key={index}>
              <Text>{item.title} spec</Text>
          </View>
          )
        }
        return(
          <View key={index} style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
            <Text>{item.sub_title} </Text>
          </View>
        )
      }};
```

Comment: What has changed here? Have you fixed the code? Please include an explanation of what this answer achieves

Comment: add `key` prop to  `<View>`  because you are rendering it in a map function. otherwise it will throw a warning.

Comment: Why we need  "index " as second parameter ?

Comment: @Jasur Kurbanov the second parameter is not needed, I only want to show it arguments